# Content flows place parent container

Tags: html, css, height

Here is the problem http://jpswebsites.com/rebound/recovery/recovery-education/134-2/

My website content background area stops at 1000px.  The min-height property is set to 1000px. Why doesn't it flow to the bottom where it meets the footer like it's suppose to?

The HTML:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="swoosh">
         <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="container">
               <div id="int-content">
                  <div id="main">
                     CONTENT IS HERE
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

The CSS

```
body{
background: white url(images/tiny_grid.png)repeat;
font: 13px Muli, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #525153;
min-width: 980px;
}

#swoosh {
background: url(images/swoosh.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#container {
margin: 10px 16px 0 16px;
background-image: url(images/container_bg.jpg);
min-height: 1000px;
}

#wrapper {
width: 980px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: url(images/cbg.png) no-repeat 0 0;
padding: 0 14px;
} 

#int-content {
margin: -5px 2px 15px 30px;
}

#main {
float: left;
width: 484px;
padding: 34px 0 0 20px;
}
```

I tried putting a height 100% on every item from  through   as tutorials suggested.  This really threw things out of whack.

Thanks in advance all!

Comment: i think it is because of the min-height?

Comment: which div adds the white background? Because the divs with `min-height: 1000px` do not have a repeating background img or colour listed.

Comment: Hey Shalom, thanks for your response. If the min-height property is in there the background does not show at all.

Comment: Thanks for responding Michael, the background image is on the container tag.